# Unit tests in kotlin with Mockk overload resolution ambiguity

Tags: spring, kotlin, unit-testing, specifications, mockk

I need to get the results of the query with specifications. In order to do that I'm using JpaSpecificationExecutor's `List<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec)` method. The problem is that I can't do the same in tests, cause it has several methods with the same parameters.
Here is my method:

```
fun getFaqList(category: FaqCategory?, subcategory: FaqCategory?, searchText: String?): List<FaqEntity> {

    val spec = Specification.where(FaqSpecification.categoryEquals(category))
        ?.and(FaqSpecification.subcategoryEquals(subcategory))
        ?.and(
            stringFieldContains("title", searchText)
                ?.or(stringFieldContains("description", searchText))
        )

    return faqRepository.findAll(spec)
}
```

And the test that I'm trying to run:

```
@MockK
private lateinit var faqRepository: FaqRepository

@InjectMockKs
private lateinit var faqService: FaqService

companion object {
    val FAQ_CATEGORY_ENTITY = FaqCategoryEntity(
        id = AGRICULTURE
    )

    val FAQ_SUBCATEGORY_ENTITY = FaqCategoryEntity(
        id = AGRICULTURE_GENERAL
    )

    val FAQ_ENTITY = FaqEntity(
        id = FAQ_ID,
        title = "title",
        description = "description",
        category = FAQ_CATEGORY_ENTITY,
        subcategory = FAQ_SUBCATEGORY_ENTITY
    )
}

@Test
fun `getFaqList - should return faq list`() {
    val faqList = listOf(FAQ_ENTITY)

    every { faqRepository.findAll(any()) } returns faqList

    val response = faqService.getFaqList(AGRICULTURE, AGRICULTURE_GENERAL, FAQ_SEARCH_TEXT)

    assertThat(response).isEqualTo(faqList)
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
public abstract fun <S : FaqEntity!> findAll(example: Example<TypeVariable(S)!>): 
(Mutable)List<TypeVariable(S)!> defined in kz.btsd.backkotlin.faq.FaqRepository
public abstract fun findAll(pageable: Pageable): Page<FaqEntity!> defined in 
kz.btsd.backkotlin.faq.FaqRepository
public abstract fun findAll(sort: Sort): (Mutable)List<FaqEntity!> defined in 
kz.btsd.backkotlin.faq.FaqRepository
public abstract fun findAll(spec: Specification<FaqEntity!>?): (Mutable)List<FaqEntity!> 
defined in kz.btsd.backkotlin.faq.FaqRepository
```

What should I write in findAll() params in order for spring to understand :

```
faqRepository.findAll(any())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem with

```
every { faqRepository.findAll(any<Specification<FaqEntity>>()) } returns faqList
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the compiler can't decide what type `any()` is supposed to be and therefore which method to pick.

I'm not sure where `any()` is coming from, but if it is from some mocking library you can probably use `any(Specification)`. Otherwise you might be able to change the signature of `any()` to return a `Specification` or cast it to `Specification`.

Comment: Yeah, I know the problem, but I can't tell spring to use exactly with the Specification method. any() comes from the mockk library. I tried to use Specification instead of any(), in that case I get other error, cause those two objects will be different. The one that I create, and the one that compiler uses. So I get no answer found error.